# Define Function Type, Function Interface in Typescript

Tags: typescript, types

Is it possible to define a function interface in typescript?

for instance, when we have things such as

```
meth (a : {b: B, c: C}) : {b: B, c: C} {...}
```

we can write

```
interface A {
    b : B;
    c : C;
}
meth (a : A) : A {...}
```

however, when we have something like

```
meth (a : (b: B) => C) : (b: B) => C {...}
```

can we do something similar, like define a function type so that we can write

```
meth (a : A) : A {...}
```

again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interfaces support call signatures. Actually the syntax you use can be seen a shorthand for the more verbose full syntax:

```
interface A 
{
    (b: B) : C
}
function meth (a : A) : A { return a; }
```

The interface syntax also has the advantage of supporting multiple overloads for the function :

```
interface A {
    (b: B): D
    (d: D, b: B): C
}
function meth(a: A) : void
{
    a(new B()); // Call overload with one argument
    a(new D(), new B()); // Call overload with two arguments 
}

meth((b: B | D, d?: D|B) => new D());
```

Comment: So I'm trying to do overloading with different types: the following does not compile: 
 ```interface AddSomething {
  (x: number, y: number): number;
  (x: string, y: string): string;
}

const somethingToAdd = (oneString: string, twoString: string): string => {
  return oneString + twoString;
};

function addWrapper(
  adder: AddSomething,
  
): void {
  console.log(adder('hello','world'));
}

addWrapper(somethingToAdd);``` When I add a type declaration to the function it says the string types are not compatible with numbers.